# How do I make this wildcard pattern?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory with the following contents:

```
1         button       e       lake      pc         se            temperature5
9         cable        floor   lamp      pipe       shovel        temperature6
axe       chute        floppy  n         pipes      silver        towel
bed       d            gold    ne        platinum   sw            u
boulder   description  ibm     nw        preserver  temperature2  urinal
box       dial         key     painting  rms        temperature3  w
bracelet  diamond      ladder  paper     s          temperature4  weight
```

I need to find a single wildcard pattern to obtain only the following:

```
axe       floppy  lamp      preserver  silver
bracelet  gold    paper     rms        towel
diamond   key     platinum  shovel     weight
```

I used `ls ??*[!1-9]` to get everything at least 3 characters long and the last character is not a numeral.

What has me confused is that I need a **single** wildcard pattern to obtain the desired result. For example, I could do something like `ls ??? ????` to get all files with 3 or 4 characters but wouldn't that be considered 2 wildcard patterns?

Comment: Right, that's an example of what I've tried. But I've done other cases such as `ls ?*[!l0-9]` where the last character can't be a numeral or the letter l. But it feels like every step like that omits both a thing that I need and don't need. In this case, I lose `towel`, `shovel`, `dial`, `urinal`, but I need to keep `towel` and `shovel`. It looks like I need to use more than one pattern to get the desired result.

Comment: What is the criterion to include `floppy` but exclude `floor`?

Comment: What are rules for your desired result?

Comment: We are recreating the game dunnet in bash. We are making an alias `getall` to get all items which are "getable". But `floor` cannot be put in inventory, so we have to exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking only for fixed set of names, you can use this:

```
ls {axe,bracelet,diamond,floppy,gold,...,weight}
```

In bash terms, this is considered a single pattern.